# Any pattern for using Maven to checkout/patch/build a non-maven based open source project?

Tags: maven, automation, patch, maven-scm

I need to have a small patch applied to the sources of an open source project before we can use the library it generates.  I'd like to automate this as much as possible, and am hoping to find some pattern that will let me:

1. check out the sources
2. apply my (very small) patch
3. build the project using it's build system (i.e., call ant)

Is there an example anywhere of doing something like this?  Right now, I'm playing with the scm and patch plugins, but it's nothing simple...

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to do this in just a couple steps, using mvn:scm:export and mvn:patch.

Essentially, you have scm:export run during the generate-sources step, exporting to your ./src/main/java/ directory, then patch runs, then the rest of your pom.xml acts as normal.

I can post a sample, but it came out pretty simple...  just took a lot of referencing of the manual.